# Snowflake Database - command for "collapsible query text" like SQL Server? Not Begin-End?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know SQL Server has Begin -- End where you can put query text that you can collapse -- mostly for usability/ readability if you have a long singular block of query text.

Does Snowflake have something similar, either in classic worksheets editor or preferably more modern SnowSight editor?

Comment: I only care about the UX. Begin isn't collapsible in Snowsight. It seems Begin End is mostly procedural stuff in Snowflake and has no bearing on UX. Am I wrong?

Comment: No it's not collapsable currently